# Unknownn, unnamed and blank icon app show up in app drawer?

Tags: applications, 8.0-oreo, f-droid

I am using FDroid on a XPeria XZ.

Today I had problem updating Street Complete.
Since, I have a unnamed, blank icon showing up in my app drawer. I can't seem to remove it even via settings.

I have tried to uninstall StreetComplete to check if that would fix the problem, no dice.

Is there any way to known how it appeared, and how to remove it?

[image: Screenshot of the app drawer showing the unknown app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing the launcher cache and rebooting device was suggested and it fixed the problem

This was recommended to clear from the memory the remanants of aborted download which  included the icon on launcher