# How can I get rid of this anonymous app?

Tags: uninstallation, app-icons

I have just found an app in my apps menu (pictured below), but it doesn't have a name or proper icon.

I have looked in the app info menu in settings, but I can't see anything.

My phone is a Sony Xperia XZ. It's running android 8.0.0

Does anyone know how to get rid of this?

[image: screen cap of my apps menu]

Comment: Can you find it in application list in settings? Can you frag and uninstall it? What does it do when you click on it?

Comment: As I said, it's not in settings. When I tap on it in that menu nothing happens. If I long tap then I can move it to home, but nothing else.

Comment: Try using [Malwarebytes Antimalware](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.malwarebytes.antimalware).

Comment: Did you try restarting your phone?

Comment: [This may help](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/189324/131553)

Comment: @abochur that seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually that is a virus app(no name and no icon and can"t uninstall) and you can uninstall it by using malware cleaner apps

Comment: Android doesn't have viruses. Maybe a malware.

Comment: I tried AVG, but it hasn't found anything

Comment: Try to use Kaspersky mobile if it don't work that mean your malware is very bad

Answer (score 0):

Go to app store and see if there is an app which is on hold and has not been downloaded yet. It might have some error and so is stuck. Else scan your phone once. It can be a malware.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this fixed it, but A bochur's suggestion to restart my phone has removed the app from the app menu.

If someone know what caused this behaviour I'd be grateful to know, otherwise: case closed.

Comment: One possible reason is aborted download - I linked one such case in the comment beneath the question

Comment: Oh! Thanks. I don't remember doing that, but it's possible.